# What is the time complexity of the following code snippet where n is a positive integer:

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, nested-loops

```
s=0; c=n; p=log(n);
for (h=1; h<p; h++) {
 c = c/2;
 for (j=1; j<c; j++) {
  for (k=1; k<=h; k++)
    s++;
 }
}
```

What is the time complexity of the following code snippet where n is a positive integer:

Comment: Is the log(n) base 2 or any?

Answer (score 1):

Using Sigma notation, you can get the exact number of iterations (Assuming log is of base 2):

[image]

You may deduce the order of growth as well (Intuitively linear, but you may prove it using **limits**):

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is any possible way the OP will understand this. Perhaps you can use this theory and apply to his specific example? (If applicable)

Comment: This is applied on the specific example. One can trace the indexes *h*, *j*, and *k*. The rest is inferrable (for instance, *c* is *n/2^k*, but the variation of *c* is not clear if kept like in the algorithm itself).